# How do I set a condition in HTML button tags to stop my Webcam Video Stream on webpage | Python Django

Tags: python, django, webcam

The webcam video stream is displayed on another webpage, so I try to stop my webcam video stream when directed to my homepage but the webcam keeps on running. How can turn it off?

here is my views.py

```
still_on = True

def gen(tryhaar):
    while still_on:
        frame = tryhaar.get_frame()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')


def video_feed(request):
    return StreamingHttpResponse(gen(VideoCamera()),
                    content_type='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

def home(request):
    return render(request, "main/home.html",{})
```

here is my html

```
{% extends 'main/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Stimulus Section</h1>
    <br>
    <img src="{% url 'video_feed' %}">
    <br>
    <br>
    <h2>{{ S6 }}</h2>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

    <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href='{% url 'home' %}'">Home</button>
{% endblock %}
```

My idea is to set a condition in my ***button*** tag to let ***still_on*** variable to be **False** when the button is clicked so that the webcam stop running. How can I do that? Or is there other way it can be done?

here is my tryhaar.py where VideoCamera class is defined just in case.

```
class VideoCamera(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    def __del__(self):
        self.video.release()

    def get_frame(self):
        success, image = self.video.read()
        raw_img = image.copy() # for dataset

        gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        eyes_detected = eyes_detection.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.3, minNeighbors=5)
        for (x, y, w, h) in eyes_detected:
            cv2.rectangle(image, pt1=(x, y), pt2=(x + w, y + h), color=(0,255,0), thickness=2)
        frame_flip = cv2.flip(image,1)
        filename = '{}.jpg'.format(time.time())
        filepath = os.path.join('raw_dataset', filename) # dataset folder
        crop_img = cv2.flip(raw_img,1)[y:y+h, x-10:x+w+10] # crop eye image
        cv2.imwrite(filepath, crop_img) # save to dataset
        ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame_flip)
        return jpeg.tobytes()
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by adding a new link to urls.py on my project and with some JavaScript. I hope codes from my project helps.

views.py

```
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'videostream/home.html')

def generator(video):

    while True:
        frame = video.get_frame()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')

def video_feed(request):
    return StreamingHttpResponse(generator(VideoCamera()),
                                 content_type='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
```

home.html

```
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<button onclick="video_on()">on</button>
<button onclick="video_off()">off</button>
<p id="wait" ></p>

<center><img id="demo" src=""></center>


<script>
function video_on() {
  document.getElementById("demo").src = "/video";
  document.getElementById("wait").innerHTML = "Turning on. . . . .";
  setTimeout(showText, 3000);

}
function showText(){
  document.getElementById("wait").innerHTML = "Done";
}

function video_off() {
  document.getElementById("demo").src = "";
  document.getElementById("wait").innerHTML = "Turned off";
}
</script>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path("video/", views.video_feed,name='video_feed'),
]
```

So actually I am when I am on my home page, I have 2 buttons on/off which control the image src with the JavaScript code. I hope you can modify this for your project.